# Latex as copyable text not as image

Tags: html, css, latex

According to https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/88, Stack Exchange sites use MathJax to format math equations.

When I looked at the demo page (http://www.mathjax.org/demos/tex-samples/), the source code for the first example is:

```
\[\begin{aligned}
\dot{x} &amp; = \sigma(y-x) \\
\dot{y} &amp; = \rho x - y - xz \\
\dot{z} &amp; = -\beta z + xy
\end{aligned} \]
```

Since the result is text, I am assuming that some fancy CSS makes it look nice like that. My question is can someone help me find a way to get that CSS and convert that code to raw HTML that looks the same?

Comment: If you are trying to get MathJax to work, you just have to have Javascript enabled on the page (specifically, the js from Mathjax.org). Note that it only works on web sites that have MathJax installed, so, for example, it works on math.stackexchange.com, but not on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I see the formatting fine. I just want to be able to duplicate that using only HTML.

Comment: Additionally the font used there is bitstream charter (accessible by `usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}`). Pure HTML/CSS solution is complicated but here is a link http://www.myphysicslab.com/web_math.html or http://www.periodni.com/mathematical_and_chemical_equations_on_web.html

Comment: You aren't going to get it by pure HTML ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Firefox, you can install a browser AddOn called "Web Developer" which will give you an added menu bar. One of the commands available from this bar is CSS/Display Style Information. You can then select any element on the page and the styling for the element will be shown in separate window at the bottom of the page. By using this, you can potentially reconstruct from scratch the HTML styling for a particular element or set of elements.